# Simple substraction on PHP (Arithmetic Operators)

Tags: php, math, subtraction

I need some help with this simple substraction:

```
$savings = ($newprice - $newvalue);
```

$newprice and `$newvalue` are values like `120.00` and `40.00`

The problem is that the result is shown as `80` , without the `.00` (dot00) at the end.

I will like to keep the values on the same format (a dot plus double cero at the end); what I need to change or include to that code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Someone called for [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/number_format

```
$savings = number_format($newprice - $newvalue, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that make the trick, just a small question, that will affect values like 40.50 or 40.99 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$savings = sprintf("%0.2f", ($newprice - $newvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check into this function:

```
number_format();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
$savings = 80;
echo number_format($savings);
```